When is x not odr-used?
In the C++ Standard
Using N4993 (Note: this is not the current standard, but it is close enough for this discussion).
In section "6.3 One-definition rule [basic.def.odr]"
Paragraph 5:

A variable is named by an expression if the expression is an id-expression that denotes it. A variable x that is named by a potentially-evaluated expression E is odr-used by E unless
(5.1) -- x is a reference that is usable in constant expressions (7.7), or
(5.2) -- x is a variable of non-reference type that is usable in constant expressions and has no mutable subobjects, and E is an element of the set of potential results of an expression of non-volatile-qualified non-class type to which the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (7.3.2) is applied, or
(5.3) -- x is a variable of non-reference type, and E is an element of the set of potential results of a discarded-value expression (7.2.3) to which the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is not applied.

And

If a local entity is odr-used in a declarative region in which it is
not odr-usable, the program is ill-formed.

Consider the following code
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A
{
    public:
        int data;
        constexpr   A() { data = 0; }
        constexpr   A(const int& n) :data(n) {}


        friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& output, const A& obj)
        {
            output << "output A: " << endl;
            output << "+data: " << obj.data << endl;
            return output;
        }
};


struct MyClass 
{
    public:
        int value = 777;
        A subobject;

        constexpr MyClass(int x) : value(x) {}
        constexpr MyClass(const MyClass& obj)
        {
            this->value = obj.value;
            this->subobject = A(obj.subobject);
        }
};


int main()
{
     static constexpr  MyClass obj(11);
     constexpr const MyClass& ref = obj;
     
     constexpr MyClass obj1(33);

     MyClass obj2(100);
     cout << obj2.value;

    [] ()
        {
            cout << ref.value << endl;  //OK, due to "ref.value" is not odr-used,
                                        //because it satisfies case 1

            cout << ref.subobject << endl; //OK, due to "ref.subobject" is not odr-used, 
                                           // because it satisfies case 1

            cout << obj1.value << endl;     //OK, due to "obj1.value" is not odr-used,
                                            //because it satisfies case 2

            cout << obj1.subobject << endl; //Error, due to "ref.subobject" is odr-used,
                                            //because it does not satisfies case 2 
                                            // (due to it is class type)

        }();
}

I don't know how to apply obj2 to case 3 so that obj2 is not odr-used in the lambda above. Help me.
Note: ODR in this context refers to "One Definition Rule".

Perhaps covered by https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition

@Eljay, it doesn't have what I need.

It's really difficult to help you as you did not explain what are your doubts and what exactly you fail to understand.

I don't know when it applies... is a bit ambiguous.  What is the it to which the comment refers?  The obj2 is not odr-usable where that //case 3 comment is located (and since obj2 is not used there, everything is okay).

@Eljay, I mean how to apply obj2 to case 3 so that obj2 is not odr-used? And one more thing ,everything is not ok as you said: the line cout << obj1.subobject << endl;  will error as I described.
